# Can this code contain buffer overflows?

Tags: c, security, buffer, stack-overflow, fgets

These days I have read about buffer overflow attacks, and actually I can't say that I have understand the big picture, I have some doubts in my mind.

So to kill my doubts the question arises, if my program is written in C and all of code used to get input or to copy/merge buffers, checks for bounds, can buffer overflow occur? Or saying directly, is input (wherever that comes) the only method that an attacker can use to cause buffer overflow?

For example, consider the following code:

```
int main(){
    int size = 15;
    char buf[size];
    fgets(buf, size , stdin);
    printf("%s",buf);}
```

Is susceptible to buffer overflows?
Thank you!:)

Comment: It does not overflow (if the specified size is not bad) fgets does not perform a write only in the area of the specified range.

Comment: There's an error though.. return value of fgets ought be checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually guys there is an error in the code, and there could be a potential security problem, coding like that in certain applications!  In short checking returns values matter.

Whilst it may be argued that his program is indeed safe, the bigger picture is about the pattern on the code, and ensuring the assumed invariants of the code, which is that buf, contains a NULL terminated string between 0 and 14 bytes long.

From man page :

> The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s, until n-1 bytes
>       are read, or a  is read and transferred to s, or an end-of-file condition is encountered.
>       The string is then terminated with a null byte.
>
> RETURN VALUE
>
> Upon successful completion, fgets() shall return s. If the stream is at end-of-file, the 
>       end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set and fgets() shall return a null pointer.
>       If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, fgets() shall return 
>       a null pointer, [CX] [Option Start]  and shall set errno to indicate the error.

Arranging for an error condition, may mean no NULL may be appended to the string and the buffer is automatically allocated, so printf(3) may leak information..   think about Heardbleed.

As chux points out initialising the automatically allocated buffer `buf[0] = '\0';`, or declaring buf statically so it's system initialised to 0, ought not be relied upon as in event of error, the state of buf is undefined.

So a check on the return value of fgets is necessary.  So something more like :

```
{ 
  char *s;
  if ((s = fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
      puts( s);
  }
}
```

Here's a link to an article on secure programming, which may be of interest http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs/

Comment: Please do not format plain text as code, it looks ugly when random words are highlighted.

Comment: `buf[0] = '\0';` does not help.  Should an IO error occur, the state of `buf` is not defined, so without checking `fgets()` results, using `buf` is not known to be valid string.  With checking the result of `fgets()`, there is no need to `buf[0] = '\0';` The advice to "better check the return value of fgets" is the best approach.  Alos best not to `printf( s);` for `s` may have `'%'` in it, better to use `fputs()`.  Otherwise, nice answer.

Comment: Thankyou it's clear now, thanks for link also. :)

Answer (score 1):

The use of 'fgets' does prevent the buffer overflow. According to the man page:

> The fgets() function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by size from the given stream and stores them in the string str.  Read-
>        ing stops when a newline character is found, at end-of-file or error.  The newline, if any, is retained.  If any characters are read and there is no error,
>        a `\0' character is appended to end the string.

Notice the 'prevent' above. If you set the size larger than the actual buffer, you can then pull in more information than the buffer can hold leading to a buffer overflow. It is advisable to use

```
sizeof(buf)
```

to prevent possibly going over the buffer size.

Comment: Good points, but you haven't considered the error case.

Comment: The man page states that "The string is then terminated with a null byte." This is after it a '\n' or 'EOF'. Why would an EOF "mean No NULL may be appended?"

Comment: @Rob11311, I don't have the points to comment on yours. Sorry.

Comment: Correct on EOF, my focus was on explaining the lurking danger in the assumptions, this shows how hard secure programming is.  You would need to find a way to cause an error condition, then it MAY fail non safely.. or the system MIGHT be safe by accident.  Just check return values.. if you care about security

Comment: Actually I thought I'd pasted in the return values on man page.. now it ought be clear!